# Is it possible to use NoTracking (MergeOption.NoTracking) with the EntityDatSource Control?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use NoTracking (MergeOption.NoTracking) with the EntityDatSource Control?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement handling for `ContextCreating` event and set `MergeOption` for `ObjectSet<T>`:

```
public partial class YourPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...

    protected void EntityDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, 
        EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Context = new YourContext();  // EntityDataSource handles disposing
        e.Context.YourObjectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
    }
}
```

And in the markup use:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ... OnContextCreating="EntityDataSource_ContextCreating" />
```

Comment: How would you recommend I integrate this into a "One ObjectContext per HTTP Request"? That seems to be the recommended framework/solution. Agree?

Comment: If you have one context you can still get the context in the handler and, set merge option and use it, don't you? Moreover when this event is called any methods where you need change tracking should be already completed so it should not cause any issues. If it does you should think about the problem from different perspective: one context per request is minimal recommended solution. You can have more contexts if you need them but you have to correctly use them and you mustn't share them among requests

Comment: Correct. I just meant "in general" how would you implement "single context per request". But, I have found several examples on line. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through ALL the ObjectSets in an Enitity? I would like to include the EntityDataSource_ContextCreating() in my BasePage and have it handle setting NoTracking on any ObjectSet that might be exposed in the contex. Although, I am not sure how to iterate through ALL the ObjectSets and I definately don't want to hard code all of them, such as: (e.context as MyEntities).Object1.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; e.context as MyEntities).Object2.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;  etc...

Comment: That can be done only through reflection because those ObjecSets are exposed on derived context instance as properties. Such reflection will be much more slower.

Comment: Yeah. I suppose I am going to have to hard code it. Should I still make a single/common method that just disables it for all my ObjectSets? I would only call this method when creating read only type EDS contexts.... Or would there be an unnecessary penalty for setting the mergeoption on all those ObjectSets that aren't exposed in the context. I probably need to do some performance testing....